# Prevent a form from submiting after checking the number of checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, django-forms

I have done some research but yet ,i have not gotten a solution that meets my need .I am trying to create a jquery function that will check the number of check boxes selected .And if selected checked boxes less than min ,the form is prevented from submitting .In my back end i am using django modelform

my Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        var numberchecked= $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
        var min =3
        if (numberchecked<min) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }

   });
});
```

Comment: you should return false to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: What does Django have to do with this? Please remove tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i was talking about in the previous comment

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    var numberchecked = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
    var min = 3
    if (numberchecked < min) {

      console.log('Not Submitting');
      return false;
    }
    console.log('Submitting');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="my-form" action="google.com">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Try to add return false to your function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").submit(function(e){
var numberchecked= $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
var min =3
 if (numberchecked<min){
  return false;
  }
}); });
```

Difference between e.preventDefault() and return false:

> The difference is that return false; takes things a bit further in
>   that it also prevents that event from propagating (or "bubbling up")
>   the DOM. The you-may-not-know-this bit is that whenever an event
>   happens on an element, that event is triggered on every single parent
>   element as well. So let's say you have a box inside a box. Both boxes
>   have click events on them. Click on the inner box, a click will
>   trigger on the outer box too, unless you prevent propagation.
>   More information: https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/

Note, i changed your selector from input:checkbox:checked to input[type=checkbox]:checked

Comment: thanks , but changing the input[type=checkbox] does not .but this works fine  input:checkbox:checked